# error: too many arguments to function 'getch'

Tags: c, getchar

```
 int i;
    char c[4]={'\0'},a[4],*pin="1234";
    do
    {
        DARK_GREY;
        printf("\nEnter 4 digit Pin: ");
        WHITE;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            // error: too many arguments to function 'getch'
            a[i]=getch(c[i]);
            printf("*");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getch();` function is used to hold the output screen for a while in the sense till any key is pressed.

```
int getch(void);
```

`getch()` have `void` parameter, so use like this :

```
a[i]=getch();
c[i] = a[i];
```